# How to change the data value of the parent file from the sub file in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a brand new app in vue.js. I want to change the data value of the app.vue using the checkbox checked used in the child component how I will do this the code I' using in both the files is:-

component file:-

```
 <template>
   <div>
    <h3>Edit the user</h3>
    <p>Local: {{ $route.query.local }}</p>
    <p>Number is:- {{ $route.query.q }}</p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" @click="change()">customizer</label>
   </div>
 </template>
 <script>
   export default{
      props:["changeParentStatus"],
      methods:{
      change() {
        this.active = !this.active
        console.log(this.active)
        this.changeParentStatus(this.active);
      }
    }
  }
 </script>
```

app.vue file

```
<template>
  <div :class="[{ 'active': active }]">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <h1>Routing</h1>
      <hr>
      <app-header></app-header>
      <router-view :changeParentStatus="changeStatus"></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AppHeader from "./components/Header.vue";
  export default {
   data(){
     return{
       active: true
     }
   },
   methods:{
      changeStatus(active){
         this.active=active
      }
   },
   components:{
      appHeader: AppHeader
   }
 }
 </script>

<style>
 .active{
   background: black;
 }
</style>
```

How will I change the value of the app.vue data active to `true or false` by changing the checkbox used in the component file. Can anybody please help me to do this.

Folder structure is:-

```
 src---> app.vue
         components---->users----->userEdit.vue (component file)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a function as an attribute to the child component

```
<app-header :changeParentStatus="changeStatus"></app-header>
```

parent
callback

```
<script>
  import AppHeader from "./components/Header.vue";
  export default {
   data(){
     return{
       active: true
     }
   },
   methods:{
       changeStatus(active){
           this.active=active
       }
   },
   components:{
      appHeader: AppHeader
   }
  }
 </script>
```

now call "changeParentStatus" from child change function

```
<script>
   export default{
    props:["changeParentStatus"],
    methods:{
       change() {
            this.active = !this.active
            console.log(this.active)
            this.changeParentStatus(this.active);
        }

    }
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: by using your code there is an error `this.changeParentStatus is not a function` can you tell me how i solve this

Comment: so if you are using it with router view , you need to pass it like this
<router-view :changeParentStatus="changeStatus"></router-view>,
and then define it in props of children
props:["changeParentStatus"].
if it does not solve you issue , please share your code.

Comment: But it will gives me error can you edit your answer and post it again that it will not show the error?? @user6761351

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to pass the checkbox value from child to parent. For this define event on parent component and emit that event from child component.

In Parent handle event like this:

```
<router-view @changeParentStatus="changeStatus"></router-view>
```

The `ChangeStatus` is event/method so we defined using `v-on`: (or `@`shorthand)

Next, emit event from child component:

```
 <label>
    <input type="checkbox" 
       @click="$emit('changeParentStatus', $event.target.checked)">
 customizer</label>
```

More info: [Vue.JS Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events)

Comment: While using your code there is also a error of the `Property or method "checked" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components` can you help to solve this?

Comment: Have you defined in data of child component? If not, define as data:{ checked: false} - it is boolean for single checkbox.

Comment: I am seeing you don't need model binding/ maintaining checked state in child, you can directly emit call to parent in click of checkbox, updated code. Now, you don't data/method in child.